# Determine which targets failed in ninja all at once

Tags: ninja

Sometimes I want to build multiple targets at once:

```
$ ninja A B C D -j10
```

It's possible that some amount of these targets could fail to build. Is there something I can that:

- will successfully build all the things that can be successfully built, and
- will report to me the list of targets that failed to build?

The following will work but I feel like there should be a more efficient way of doing this:

```
for target in A B C D; do
    if ! ninja ${target} -j10 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then 
        echo "${target} failed"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled upon this because I had the same question.

> Is there something I can that will successfully build all the things that can be successfully built [...]

Yes, like in `make` you can provide the `-k` option.

`-k N     keep going until N jobs fail [default=1]`

Continue building until all tasks finished or failed:

```
ninja -k 0
```

**Combine this with knowing that failed targets will be listed as `FAILED: <target_name>` on stdout:**

```
ninja -k0 | grep FAILED > failed_targets.log
```